# For what sequence is $A(x^{2})$ a generating function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

Let $A(x)$ be the generating function for $\{a_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$.

For what sequence is $A(x^{2})$ a generating function?

---

Let's say we have another generating function $B(x)$ for $\{b_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$. Then for example for $A(x) + B(x)$ the sequence would be $\{a_{n} + b_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and for $A(x)B(x)$ it would be a Cauchy product. For $A(x^{2})$ though I have no idea how to even start thinking about it.

Comment: Write down the actual series for $A(x)$ at put $x^2$ in place of $x$. You will see that the coefficients of odd powers are all $0$. What is the corresponding sequence then?

Comment: @Gary Do you mean to do the following? $$A(x^{2}) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_{n}x^{2n} = a_{0} + a_{1}x^{2} + a_{2}x^{4} + ...\ ,$$I'm not sure how to see the corresponding sequence from this.

Comment: $A(x^2) = a_0 + 0x + a_1x^2 + 0x^3 + a_2x^4 + \cdots$

Comment: @MartinR Is the corresponding sequence $a_{0} + 0 + a_{1} + 0 + a_{2} + ...$? If so, how do I express it in the form $\{ ... \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$? The sequence seemingly is just $\{a_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ no? since we're essentially just adding up the $a_{n}$'s $a_{0} + a_{1} + ... + a_{n}$ giving us the original sequence.

Comment: The sequence is $a_n$ when $n$ is even and $0$ when $n$ is odd: $a_0,0,a_1,0,a_2,0,\ldots$. What you wrote is the sum of the terms, i.e., the corresponding series formed from the sequence. You can say that the sequence is $(b_n)_{n\geq 0}$ where $b_{2n}=a_n$ and $b_{2n+1}=0$.

Comment: Actually it is $b_n = a_{n/2}$ if $n$ is even, and $b_n = 0$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: Ok, your answers make sense. Write an actual answer to the question and I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ is the generating function of the sequence $\{a_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ then
$$
 A(x^2) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{2n} = a_0 + 0x + a_1x^2 + 0x^3 + a_2x^4 + \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n
$$
is the generating function of the sequence $\{b_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ defined as
$$
b_n = \begin{cases}
 a_{n/2} & \text{if $n$ is even,} \\
 0 & \text{if $n$ is odd.} \\
\end{cases}
$$